# Is it possible to do Integration of machine learning algorithm in python on the web

Tags: javascript, python, scikit-learn, nltk

I've designed a machine learning algorithm for the chatbot in python which uses different libraries sklearn, NLTK etc. This algorithm takes an input from the user and replies based on the query user has entered.

1. Is there any possible way to integrate this algorithm (in python)
   with Website(HTML, CSS, JavaScript).
2. If option 1 above isn't possible, then, is there any tool available to covert the python code (with sklearn, NLTK libraries)  into javascript code.
3. If both the option 1 and 2 are not possbile, then, is there python libraries like sklearn, NLTK libraries available in JavaScript to implement machine learning.

Comment: https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/169/ maybe this can help you? I never used it, just searched right now

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom `PHP`, you can use its `ML library` as it would be easily integrated [visit this link](https://packagist.org/packages/php-ai/php-ml). But note that it does not provide much of features.

And if you are to use the `Python ML-kit` then it depends on the web framework you are using, frameworks provides an intermediate environment to execute other languages code and integrate them.

I was using `Laravel Framework` for web development and I had to use Python Algorithm for recommendations, so I searched and I found `symfony` dependency of Laravel to execute my Python and it was easy to use.

And for `JavaScript ML-Kit`, [this link](https://medium.com/tensorflow/introducing-tensorflow-js-machine-learning-in-javascript-bf3eab376db) might help you, `TensorFlow.js` is a ML-Library in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert Python to JavaScript.

If your ML algorithm is working fine then, you can integrate it with any web-based application.

**How to integrate ML (made with Python) into JavaScript Websites?**

If your ML model works fine then, it doesn't matter who is giving input to it. It will always return the correct result.

You can use something like Flask or Django to create your own APIs in Python. These APIs will take input from the client-side (made in HTML, CSS, JS, etc) and will take that input to the ML model then, it can respond back to the client.

[image: Web-ML-Integration]

Comment: What if i want to integrate, without using any server-side language?

Comment: If we are talking about some real-world application then you shouldn't. We don't store our logics or model on the client-side.